# Is this circuit wired in parallel?

Tags: transistors, parallel

Sorry for the amateurish question. I am planning to tap into my car battery's reverse fuse to signal when it's time to receive a wireless signal from a rear-view camera. The camera-feed receiver in my circuit needs a 5V power source, which I want to activate when the reverse lights are on. Normally, the 5V is powering the phone, which receives data from the receiver. Anyway, I was wondering if I designed the circuit correctly.

I have my doubts about the connection to the base of the transistor and whether it will receive any current at all when the reverse lights are on. I know that in parallel circuits current flows through all possible routes from high potential (positive) to low potential (negative), but I am not sure where the negative terminal is for the circuit that includes the transistor. It seems to awkwardly end at the base of the transistor. Would appreciate any thoughts on why this may or may not work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0I79h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This circuit does nothing at all.

Comment: shouldn't you want to turn on the camera when the reverse lights are on? .... anyway, in the existing schematic above, put the receiver where the 5 V battery is ... put the 5 V battery where the receiver is, positive at top ... connect the Q1 emitter to the negative terminal of the 12 V battety and increase R3 to something like 4.7 k ohms

Comment: oops you're right, will edit question

Comment: No the transistor would not work because current only flows if there is a return path available for it. Secondly what type of power source is the 5V, is it an isolated 5V battery bank because if that 5V is being derived from your 12V battery aswell then your ground is already common between the two circuits. Additionally do you want to power the recieved when pressing brake of putting vehicle in reverse gear? Should the receiver turn off immediately when you release the brake.

Comment: yes the 5V is from the cigarette lighter. yes the reverse gear should trigger the receiver.

Comment: thanks for the tips. what I've gathered is the circuit should be revised to show both voltage sources share a common ground and the npn transistor's emitter and collector should be flipped

Comment: at least 2 electrical pathways that share common terminals

Comment: Another option is to use an optical switch (optocoupler/solid state relay), then the circuits are isolated from each other.

Comment: No such thing as serial or parallel in the case of that transistor. The obvious parallel thing in the circuit the the phone which is in parallel with the 5V power source.